# What does this syntax involving Entity mean?

Tags: argument-patterns

I came across a different style of input while defining functions. Though I tried playing with this form, I have not understood how to interpret this input.

```
Country[country:Entity["Country", _]]:=
```

How different is it from the below-given input that I usually follow?

```
Country[country_String]:=
```

Comment: `Entity` is an object that represents a real world bit of data with properties and things like that. Check the [entity framework docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/KnowledgeRepresentationAndAccess.html) for more.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I know about Entity. I am not sure as to what does this input mean w.r.t the first code Country["Bahamas"].

Comment: I'm unclear as to what the confusion is, unfortunately. Mathematica objects are basically structural and some `Entity["Country", "Bahamas"]` is the true form of the Bahamas entity. The first definition just means have the function take an `Entity` as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mathematica, the part that goes inside the brackets in a function definition can be any pattern. Thus, here is a valid function definition and usage:

```
f[xyz[x_, y_], qwerty[z_]] := {x, y, z}
f[xyz[1, 2], qwerty[3]]
```

> `{1, 2, 3}`

`f[xy[1,2], qwerty[3]]` f.e. will not evaluate at all because the arguments don't match the pattern.

Here is another example utilizing the `:` style of labeling parts of the pattern:

```
f[list : {foo[_], bar[_]}] := list
f[{foo[1], bar[2]}]
```

> `{foo[1], bar[2]}`

In this case, `list` is a label for the expression that follows, but the function will not evaluate at all if the pattern does not match the input, so e.g. `f[{fo[1], bar[2]}]` will not evaluate.

Entities are usually rendered like this in the frontend:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but like for all other typeset things in the frontend, there is also a plain text equivalent:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From the point of view of pattern matching, it is the plain text version that matters. Consequently, we may write

```
f[country: Entity["Country", _]]:= country
```

This will only evaluate if the input argument is in the form `Entity["Country", (*Anything goes here*)]`. Otherwise, it won't evaluate at all, just like in the examples that I showed earlier.

Some examples:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The country does not have to exist for this function definition to match:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is very different from the other function definition that you mention. `f[country_String]`. You can only pass a string to this function, a function defined in that way will not evaluate on entities. If you are writing a function that deals with countries, it will often be desired to have them play nicely with the built-in country entities, and then you would instead use the `f[country: Entity["Country", _]]` definition.

You could also use a hybrid:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you have a flexible function that can accept both country names as strings and countries as entities.